# Assembly language OS boot loader "using of nonexisting segment register 7" error

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I'm currently working on a basic OS for a university assignment. I am working in x86 assembly language.
I seem to have an issue with switching to the second stage of my boot-loader, resulting in the error above when I try to run the application in Bochs. From my testing, I think that the error is a result of the application not reading the program from memory properly, either due to a mistake in the first stage of my boot loader or something being wrong in the makefile. I will include both of these below:

First Stage of bootloader:

```
BITS 16

ORG 7C00h
jmp     Real_Mode_Start 

%include "functions_16.asm"

Read_Failed:
  mov       si, boot_error
  call Console_WriteLine_16
  ret

Real_Mode_Start:
  cli                                   
  xor   ax, ax                       
  mov   ss, ax
  mov   sp, 4000h

  mov   ds, ax                      

  mov   si, boot_message            
  call  Console_WriteLine_16

  mov   al, 5                       
  mov       bx, 9000h                   
  mov       ch, 0                       
  mov       dh, 0                       
  mov       dl, 0 
  mov       cl, 2                       
  int       13h
  cmp       al, 5                       
  jne       Read_Failed

  jmp   9000h

  hlt                                   


; Data
boot_message:   db  'MacOS Remastered' , 0
boot_error:     db  'Boot Failed' , 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

dw 0AA55h
```

Makefile:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL:=all
Imgname=MacRemastered
.SUFFIXES: .iso .img .bin .asm

%.bin: %.asm
nasm -w+all -f bin -o $@ $<

boot.bin: boot.asm functions_16.asm 
boot2.bin: boot.asm functions_16.asm

$(Imgname).iso: boot.bin boot2.bin
cp floppy_image/$(Imgname).img $(Imgname).img
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=boot.bin of=$(Imgname).img
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc seek=1 if=boot2.bin of=$(Imgname).img
rm -rf cdiso
mkdir cdiso
cp $(Imgname).img cdiso/$(Imgname).img
mkisofs -o $(Imgname).iso -b $(Imgname).img cdiso/  

all: $(Imgname).iso

clean:
rm -f boot.bin
rm -f boot2.bin
rm -f $(Imgname).img
rm -f $(Imgname).iso
rm -rf cdiso
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind giving us a hint as to which line it is reporting the error on?  The bootsector that you have posted looks fine.  It could very well be in the subsequent code you're loading.

Comment: Awesome, setting ah to 2 fixed it. I haven't even touched the mov dl, 0 part yet but will have a look at that next.

Comment: I can't give you +rep for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review the docs for [Int 13h/ah=2h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm). [Ralf Brown's Interrupt guide](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) is the bible of DOS and BIOS interrupts. The guide says this:

> DISK - READ SECTOR(S) INTO MEMORY
>
> ```
> AH = 02h
> AL = number of sectors to read (must be nonzero)
> CH = low eight bits of cylinder number
> CL = sector number 1-63 (bits 0-5)
> high two bits of cylinder (bits 6-7, hard disk only)
> DH = head number
> DL = drive number (bit 7 set for hard disk)
> ES:BX -> data buffer
> ```
>
> Return:
>
> ```
> CF set on error
> if AH = 11h (corrected ECC error), AL = burst length
> CF clear if successful
> AH = status (see #00234)
> AL = number of sectors transferred (only valid if CF set for some BIOSes)
> ```

Most issues are related to your disk read:

- You should set ES to 0 as the buffer is an address specified by ES:BX.
- Don't set DL to zero. The BIOS will set DL to the boot drive before transferring to your code.
- You didn't set *AH* to 2 which tells `Int 13h` that you want to do a disk read.
- Rather than `cmp al, 5` `jne Read_Failed` to test for disk error you can check the Carry Flag(CF). Replace both those lines with a simple `jc Read_Failed` right after `Int 13h`

I also recommend using the *BOCHS* debugger for 16-bit real mode debugging. When the *BOCHS* debugger starts set a breakpoint at 0x7c00 with the command `b 0x7c00` then use the command `c` to continue. That should start the *BOCHS* startup and should break at the beginning of the boot sector. Basic commands:

- `help` for a list of commands
- `n` (next)
- `s` (step)
- `c` will continue until next break point.
- `b address` breaks on an address. ie: `b 0x7c00`